# How convert a char[] string to int in the Linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

How convert char[] to int in linux kernel

with validation that the text entered is actually an int?

```
int procfile_write(struct file *file, const char *buffer, unsigned long count,
       void *data)
{

   char procfs_buffer[PROCFS_MAX_SIZE];

    /* get buffer size */
   unsigned long procfs_buffer_size = count;
   if (procfs_buffer_size > PROCFS_MAX_SIZE ) {
       procfs_buffer_size = PROCFS_MAX_SIZE;
   }

   /* write data to the buffer */
   if ( copy_from_user(procfs_buffer, buffer, procfs_buffer_size) ) {
       return -EFAULT;
   }

   int = buffer2int(procfs_buffer, procfs_buffer_size);

   return procfs_buffer_size;
}
```

Comment: Are you essentially looking for `atoi` with better validation?

Comment: the kernel does not have either `atoi` nor `strtol` as such - the "C/C++ standard library" is only available to userspace applications. For many such functions there are functional equivalents in kernel land, though, but not necessarily with the same name.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

See the various incarnations of `kstrtol()` in [`#include <include/linux/kernel.h>`](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=include/linux/kernel.h) in your friendly linux source tree.

Which one you need depends on whether the `*buffer` is a user or a kernel address, and on how strict your needs on error handling / checking of the buffer contents are (things like, is `123qx` invalid or should it return `123` ?).

Comment: Yes, `strict_strtol()` or `simple_strtol()` will probably do the job here.

Comment: 123dew is invalid
and i need to check thas a user adderss

Comment: See also https://lkml.org/lkml/2011/4/12/361 regarding the `kstrtol...()` funcs vs. `simple_strtol()` and/or `strict_strtol()`. In any case, you're right if you're not on bleeding edge use those. See that also regarding "user address".

Comment: It's a mistake. `kstrotox()` are not the replacements for `simple_strtox()` ones.

Answer (score 7):

**Minimal runnable `kstrtoull_from_user` `debugfs` example**

The `kstrto*_from_user` family is very convenient when dealing with user data.

kstrto.c:

```
#include <linux/debugfs.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <uapi/linux/stat.h> /* S_IRUSR */

static struct dentry *toplevel_file;

static ssize_t write(struct file *filp, const char __user *buf, size_t len, loff_t *off)
{
    int ret;
    unsigned long long res;
    ret = kstrtoull_from_user(buf, len, 10, &res);
    if (ret) {
        /* Negative error code. */
        pr_info("ko = %d\n", ret);
        return ret;
    } else {
        pr_info("ok = %llu\n", res);
        *off= len;
        return len;
    }
}

static const struct file_operations fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .write = write,
};

static int myinit(void)
{
    toplevel_file = debugfs_create_file("lkmc_kstrto", S_IWUSR, NULL, NULL, &fops);
    if (!toplevel_file) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

static void myexit(void)
{
    debugfs_remove(toplevel_file);
}

module_init(myinit)
module_exit(myexit)
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Usage:

```
insmod kstrto.ko
cd /sys/kernel/debug
echo 1234 > lkmc_kstrto
echo foobar > lkmc_kstrto
```

Dmesg outputs:

```
ok = 1234
ko = -22
```

Tested in Linux kernel 4.16 with [this QEMU + Buildroot setup](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/2427a322fc4a187c47998bc915f7d4dab0938aeb/kernel_module/kstrto.c).

For this particular example, you might have wanted to use [`debugfs_create_u32`](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/2427a322fc4a187c47998bc915f7d4dab0938aeb/kernel_module/debugfs.c#L55) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the unavailability of a lot of common function/macros in linux kernel, you can not use any direct function to get integer value from a string buffer.

This is the code that I have been using for a long time for doing this and it can be used on all *NIX flavors (probably without any modification).

This is the modified form of code, which I used a long time back from an open source project (don't remember the name now).

```
#define ISSPACE(c)  ((c) == ' ' || ((c) >= '\t' && (c) <= '\r'))
#define ISASCII(c)  (((c) & ~0x7f) == 0)
#define ISUPPER(c)  ((c) >= 'A' && (c) <= 'Z')
#define ISLOWER(c)  ((c) >= 'a' && (c) <= 'z')
#define ISALPHA(c)  (ISUPPER(c) || ISLOWER(c))
#define ISDIGIT(c)  ((c) >= '0' && (c) <= '9')

unsigned long mystr_toul (
    char*   nstr,
    char**  endptr,
    int base)
{
#if !(defined(__KERNEL__))
    return strtoul (nstr, endptr, base);    /* user mode */

#else
    char* s = nstr;
    unsigned long acc;
    unsigned char c;
    unsigned long cutoff;
    int neg = 0, any, cutlim;

    do
    {
        c = *s++;
    } while (ISSPACE(c));

    if (c == '-')
    {
        neg = 1;
        c = *s++;
    }
    else if (c == '+')
        c = *s++;

    if ((base == 0 || base == 16) &&
        c == '0' && (*s == 'x' || *s == 'X'))
    {
        c = s[1];
        s += 2;
        base = 16;
    }
    if (base == 0)
        base = c == '0' ? 8 : 10;

    cutoff = (unsigned long)ULONG_MAX / (unsigned long)base;
    cutlim = (unsigned long)ULONG_MAX % (unsigned long)base;
    for (acc = 0, any = 0; ; c = *s++)
    {
        if (!ISASCII(c))
            break;
        if (ISDIGIT(c))
            c -= '0';
        else if (ISALPHA(c))
            c -= ISUPPER(c) ? 'A' - 10 : 'a' - 10;
        else
            break;

        if (c >= base)
            break;
        if (any < 0 || acc > cutoff || (acc == cutoff && c > cutlim))
            any = -1;
        else
        {
            any = 1;
            acc *= base;
            acc += c;
        }
    }

    if (any < 0)
    {
        acc = INT_MAX;
    }
    else if (neg)
        acc = -acc;
    if (endptr != 0)
        *((const char **)endptr) = any ? s - 1 : nstr;
    return (acc);
#endif
}
```

Comment: Portability is ok but reimplementation is hardly the best thing for kernel code; when you talk "other UNIXes" then e.g. the Solaris kernel _does_ have `strtol()` (even documented in the Solaris section 9 manpages, so does FreeBSD (it's in libkern). Linux has it though named differently. On all of these, a `#define` would do ...

Comment: @FrankH, Agreed. but I am sure, if your code is to be shipped on a lot of os's (like the 1 I am working on), you will surely find atleast 1 that doesn't support/has implemented the required function. Anyways, I totally agree that its always better to use an existing code instead of using your own in such places.

Comment: This is just flat out wrong.  As the other answer says, Linux does have very usable functions for converting strings to integers.

Comment: @Roland Just because an accepted answer says so doesn't mean that that is correct. Please read my second comment on this post, hope that will clear your doubt. And I seriously couldn't think of a reason for the down vote.

Comment: The question relates to the linux kernel.  Other kernels? who cares.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `strtoul` or `strtol`. Here's a link to the man pages:

http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strtoul.3.html

http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strtol.3.html

Comment: AFAIK, you can not use them directly in kernel mode and even if it is available in some form in some kernel, this is not guaranteed to work on all *NIX platforms for sure.

Comment: @Vikram: I wasn't aware of this constraint.

Answer (score 0):

I use sscanf() (the kernel version) to scan from a string stream, and it works on 2.6.39-gentoo-r3. Frankly, I could never get simple_strtol() to work in the kernel--I am currently figuring out why this doesn't work on my box.

```
  ...
  memcpy(bufActual, calc_buffer, calc_buffer_size);
  /* a = simple_strtol(bufActual, NULL, 10); */ // Could not get this to work
  sscanf(bufActual, "%c%ld", &opr, &a); // places '+' in opr and a=20 for bufActual = "20+\0"
  ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Use atoi and isdigit (note isdigit just takes a char).
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/isdigit/

Comment: you have `isdigit()` (in `<linux/ctype.h>` though not `<ctype.h>`) in the Linux kernel, but there is no `atoi()`.