# Converting string to int using sprintf inside linux kernel

Tags: c, arrays, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to convert the char array into `int` using the `sprintf` but always getting segmentation fault (core dumped).

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  unsigned int n;
  sprintf("ff01","%u",n);
  printf("value of n = %u ",n);
}
```

What wrong I am doing here? `sprintf` is used to store the data in the formatted string format but cant it be used to retrieve the `int` from the string?

I need to to do this inside the linux kernel.

Comment: You should read the man for sprintf. First param is a char * to STORE the result.

Comment: "*cant it be used to retrieve the int from the string?*" - No, it can't. Are you thinking of `sscanf`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How convert char\[\] to int in Linux kernel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139493/how-convert-char-to-int-in-linux-kernel)

Answer (score 4):

To convert a number in a string to an integer, you can use the `strtol()` function.

```
n = strtol("ff01", NULL, 16);
```

Comment: strtol() is not available in linux kernel. For me the only thing works is sscanf().

Answer (score 1):

[`sprintf()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sprintf.htm)'s first argument is :

> str − This is the pointer to an array of char elements where the
>   resulting C string is **stored**.

You're passing in a string literal which can't be modified, `sprintf` tries to modify it -> segfault.

You probably meant [`sscanf()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sscanf.htm). Note that you need to pass the address of n `&n` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You should use sscanf() to achieve this.
Here is probably what you're trying to do:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int n;
    sscanf("ff01", "%x", &n);
    printf("value of n = %u \n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Always check the return value of `scanf`.

Comment: can I use it inside the Linux - kernel? or is there some other implementation?

Comment: Yes, sscanf() function is implemented in Linux kernel

Comment: looks like sscanf() is my only option because it works.